# jQuery Draggable elements inside a draggable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a panel (div) that I can reposition (aka draggable) around the page.  Inside that div are divs that are also draggable.  It seems I can either make the parent div draggable or the inner divs draggable.  Anyone know if this is possible to make both the parent container draggable and the inner divs draggable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div class="child">
    child1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    child2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    child3
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#parentDiv').draggable();
$('.child').draggable({
  containment: "parent"
});
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/gjw5o0jd/8/)